# Creating a controller that handles file uploads

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to create a controller that handles uploading files to user specific folders.  I currently have a from that allows users to upload a file which sends the post data to the controller.

What I would like the controller to do is take the uploaded file, and place it in a folder e.g. `/public/{username}/files`

But I am not too sure how to approach it using symfony.

Comment: Have a look at the Cookbook-entry "How to handle File Uploads with Doctrine": http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

Comment: ah no I havent, didn't think about Doctrine, still really new to this haha. thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mahok commented, the Symfony2 docs are useful here.

I would [follow them](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) with the added additions.  When you save the document, pass the username:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    //get the user and pass the username to the upload method
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $document->upload($user->getUsername());

    $em->persist($document);
    $em->flush();

    $this->redirect(...);
}
```

When you upload the file, use the username:

```
public function upload($username)
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }
    //use the username for the route
    $this->file->move(
        "/public/$username/files/",
        $this->file->getClientOriginalName()
    );

    // set the path property to the filename where you've saved the file
    $this->path = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();

    // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
    $this->file = null;
}
```

Saving it this way you wont actually need to use the extra entity methods like "getAbsolutePath" etc

Note that you may have to slugify the username if you accept spaces etc.

Edit:
You will need to set up a oneToMany relationship for users to files so that you can locate the file later on.

Comment: Ah I had no idea I could use Doctrine to make it simpler, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might help you---

```
$upload_dir = "your upload directory/{username}";           
if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
    @mkdir($upload_dir, "755", true);
}
move_uploaded_file($source,$destination);
```